# Replace Icons with text in the Dock

Tags: 23.04, dock, desktop-icons

Ubuntu 23...

Can I (how) show the pinned items in the Dock as text?

(For me, all icons are "mystery meat".)

Comment: Please provide a little more details regarding the issue along with screenshots.

Comment: Hovering your mouse cursor over the icon pinned in your Dock will display the program name text. If that is not a solution for you, Please [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1491506/edit) your question and add the names of a few programs icons you want to change.

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately it is not possible to configure the Ubuntu Dock to show text instead of icons. I also am not aware of alternative dock software that could do this.

Answer (score 1):

Hovering your mouse cursor over the icon pinned in your Dock will display the program name text.

The program icon can be edited to show text (As shown in this example). This Icon edit looks nice, but it's not so pretty once it's scaled down and displayed in the Dock. It will be almost too small to read. (At least for my aging eyes)

[image]

To make this icon I used Pinta to edit a copy of the original Telegram icon at `~/.local/share/icons/telegram.png`.

Answer (score 0):

I installed KDE/Plasma as an alternate desktop environment, replacing the Gnome desktop environment.

Much less mystery meat. Still runs Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can create SVG's of those icons with text, then copy them to ~/.local/share/icons/

I use inkscape, import the icon, create a text box and start typing.